# How to send a file from an external API to client without saving on server?

Tags: javascript, express, fs

I'm trying to generate a PDF with an external API, then return that PDF to the client without saving it to the server. I know that I need to use fs.createReadStream or pipe, but I can't figure out how to implement it. I'm using Express on the backend and axios on the frontend, though I'm happy to use anything that works. It only needs to work for Chrome because this is an internal tool.

The PDF returns and saves properly with a CURL, but somehow is not saving server side when I use the JS API (ideally it wouldn't have to save, but it doesn't matter as long as it gets to the client). I've tried a few variations of pipe and readStream and writeStream, as well as just returning .pipe(res) from the API call, and I can get a blank PDF to download on the client side, but it never has the data.

Here is the code for the front end:

```
  .then((response)=>{
    console.log('done', response)
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
   })
```

And the back end:

```
app.post('/pdf', async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body.data;
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=result.pdf"
  });

  await request.post('https://www.pdfotter.com/api/v1/pdf_templates/[templateID]/fill')
    .form(data)
    .auth([API KEY], '')
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('result.pdf'));

    const filePath =  __dirname + '/result.pdf';

    // Check if file specified by the filePath exists 
    fs.exists(filePath, (exists) => {
      if(exists) {     
        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
      } else {
        res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end("ERROR File does not exist");
      }
    });

  }
```

Ideally I would like to use the API to create a PDF, then return the PDF to the client (or pass the PDF to Google Drive) without saving on the server.

Comment: Pass the buffer object to `write()` directly, `res.write(data,"binary")`

Comment: While not an answer to your question, your use of the 400 error-code here appears to be a mistake. A 400 is for "Bad Request". As indicated by your own code, the more appropriate code would be a 404 - File Not Found. ;)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying I should do .pipe(res.write) (that throws an error)? Where is the buffer object if it's not in the pipe, and if it is in the pipe, how do I access it?

Comment: The buffer object is what would be returned by the `request.post()`. But if you just want to pipe() it to the client i think it would just be `.pipe(res)`

Comment: @PatrickEvans .pipe(res) definitely sends some kind of data back, and the front end code pops up a PDF download properly, but the file is blank. I've checked the API with CURL/Postman and it's working properly. It should at least send the template back blank, but it's not.